# jQuery not working outside of JS Bin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an odd issue. I have a simple page that uses jQuery and CSS, and even though I have the code to embed jQuery via Google API, the javascript isn't working on either my local machine or my web server.

It works fine on JS Bin (http://jsbin.com/oyimes/2/edit), just not when I put it all together in Dreamweaver. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
```

JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript Document

$('.subtitles').hide();

$('#title1').click(function(){
  $('#title1subtitles').slideToggle(750,function(){
    $('#title1subtitles li div').animate({width:'100%'}, 1500);
  });
});

$('#title3').click(function(){
  $('#title3subtitles').slideToggle(400,function(){
    $('#title3subtitles li div').animate({width:'100%'}, 1500);
  });
});

$('#title4').click(function(){
  $('#title4subtitles').slideToggle(400,function(){
    $('#title4subtitles li div').animate({width:'100%'}, 1500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Just FYI, you are loading jquery twice in your html. Remove the second one.

Comment: The learn center explains how to set up jQuery properly: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your js code in [`$(document).ready(function()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.subtitles').hide();

    $('#title1').click(function(){
      $('#title1subtitles').slideToggle(750,function(){
        $('#title1subtitles li div').animate({width:'100%'}, 1500);
      });
    });

    $('#title3').click(function(){
      $('#title3subtitles').slideToggle(400,function(){
        $('#title3subtitles li div').animate({width:'100%'}, 1500);
      });
    });

    $('#title4').click(function(){
      $('#title4subtitles').slideToggle(400,function(){
        $('#title4subtitles li div').animate({width:'100%'}, 1500);
      });
    });
});
```

The reason it is working in jsbin is, that it adds the `$(document).ready(function(){` for you

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping it was something as simple as that.